# Why is the change of temperature in calorimeter so small?

Tags: thermodynamics

I performed an experiment recently where I tested the specific heat capacity of different metals in water. The temperature was recorded. The metals were then removed from the beaker and placed into a calorimeter, and the temperature was recorded. Why is the change in temperature inside the calorimeter very small?

Answer (score 1):

Change in temperature is small because heat capacity of metals in general is small compared to water. Still, it depends on some other parameters, like the mass of water in calorimeter and the mass of your metal sample, initial temperature of the sample before putting it into the water etc...but your question is not clear enough so this is all I can tell you.

Comment: For a given amount of heat, smaller heat capacity should lead to a _larger_ change in temperature.

Comment: Yes, if a material has small heat capacity, then by definition this is of course true. But that is not what I meant. If iron has small heat cap compared to water then when it gives its heat to water, total temperature of this mixture wont change by much id est, you need iron to be very hot for temperature to change by some larger amount.

Comment: Hi, the experiment involved finding the heat capacity of three unknown metals. The metals were placed into a water bath one at a time until thermal equilibrium was reached and then quickly placed into a calorimeter where the temperature was noted. I noticed that the change in temperature in the calorimeter was quite small. Thanks for the answers. Here's more information??